# Update XML node (in an XML column) in SQL Server 2005 with another column value in the same row

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a temp table with an `XML` column (`XMLColumn`) and a `VARCHAR` column (`ABCColumn`).

I am trying to replace the value of a particular XML node within `XMLColumn` with the value that is in `ABCColumn` of the same row. I need to do this for every row within the temp table. Is this possible to do without a cursor that would hold the replacement value for each fetch?

I have tried doing an update to the temp table using

```
XmlColumn.modify('replace value of ... with ...')
```

but I do not have a variable in this case. I need to get the value of a `XYZColumn` and use it as the replacement value. Every example I have seen either uses a variable or a hardcoded value - not a column value of the same row.

Also, I am using SQL Server 2005. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like This:

```
UPDATE  YourTable
SET     xml_col.modify(
    'replace value of (/root/val/text())[1] with sql:column("val_col")'
    )
```

(thanks to Andromar;  I just edited his answer and used his SQLFiddle, (which works for this one too.))

Comment: I just wrote and ran it on SQL 2005, so yes.

Comment: Awesome.  For some reason, I was thinking that sql:column (and its other variations) were a 2008 thing.

Comment: AFAIK, they've been in SQL 2005 all along.

Comment: Well, you learn something new (and in this case very useful) every day. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: I voted for RBarryYoung's answer, use that instead!**

Only way I can think of is a cursor:

```
declare cur_t cursor for (select id, val_col from YourTable)
declare @id int
declare @val int
open cur_t

fetch cur_t into @id, @val
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
    update  YourTable
    set     xml_col.modify(
        'replace value of (/root/val/text())[1] with sql:variable("@val")')
    where   id = @id
    fetch cur_t into @id, @val
    end  

close cur_t
deallocate cur_t
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba805/4)

Comment: This is basically what I was doing before I decided to stop and ask if there was a better way.