# SQL Server 'FOR XML' getting value into "row" element node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml

This is another 'for xml' question, but I'm unsure whether this can be done without explicit mode. If it can't, then I'll just have to live with it.

The following is my select statement currently:

```
    SELECT
        [stream_id] as '@stream_id',
        [path_locator] as '@path_locator',
        [parent_path_locator] as '@parent_path_locatr',
        [file_type] as '@file_type',
        [cached_file_size] as '@cached_file_size',
        [creation_time] as '@creation_time',
        [last_write_time] as '@last_write_time',
        [last_access_time] as '@last_access_time',
        [is_directory] as '@is_directory',
        [is_offline] as '@is_offline',
        [is_hidden] as '@is_hidden',
        [is_readonly] as '@is_readonly',
        [is_archive] as '@is_archive',
        [is_system] as '@is_system',
        [is_temporary] as '@is_temporary',
        [name] as '/name',
        dbo.udf_GetChildren(path_locator)
    FROM @Merged
    WHERE path_locator.GetLevel() = 1
    FOR XML PATH'file'), ROOT('files'), TYPE
```

This outputs the following xml:

```
 <files>
   <file stream_id="" etc...>
      <name>NAME</name>
   </file>
 </files>
```

This isn't bad, but what I'd really like is to get the **name** element's value as the value of the **file** element. This is such a simple task I assume it can be done without explicit mode, but I've been wrong pretty often about such things.

I've tried using the '/' marker, but this doesn't seem to have the effect I want (for example [Update XML node (in an XML column) in SQL Server 2005 with another column value in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271297/update-xml-node-in-an-xml-column-in-sql-server-2005-with-another-column-value)).

**edit:**
The desired xml would be simply this:

```
 <files>
   <file stream_id="" etc...>NAME</file>
 </files>
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show an example of the desired XML output?

Comment: Have you tried `name as '*'`?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson -- see my answer -- * should work too though...

Comment: @sgeddes yep, make the column name go away and the data end up in the "current" instead of creating a new sub node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `name as '*'`

[Columns with a Name Specified as a Wildcard Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500154.aspx)

Comment: @Adam there are many ways to skin a cat. All answers here will do the job so +1 to all of you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to remove the Column Name from the field -- I was able to do this with concatonating a blank space to the end.  Here is a condensed version that you should be able to get to work with your above example:

```
SELECT name + ''
FROM TestXML
FOR XML PATH('file')
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1f14f/25).

And a good article about it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510469.aspx

Here it is with your above query:

```
SELECT
    [stream_id] as '@stream_id',
    [path_locator] as '@path_locator',
    [parent_path_locator] as '@parent_path_locatr',
    [file_type] as '@file_type',
    [cached_file_size] as '@cached_file_size',
    [creation_time] as '@creation_time',
    [last_write_time] as '@last_write_time',
    [last_access_time] as '@last_access_time',
    [is_directory] as '@is_directory',
    [is_offline] as '@is_offline',
    [is_hidden] as '@is_hidden',
    [is_readonly] as '@is_readonly',
    [is_archive] as '@is_archive',
    [is_system] as '@is_system',
    [is_temporary] as '@is_temporary',
    [name] + '',
    dbo.udf_GetChildren(path_locator)
FROM @Merged
WHERE path_locator.GetLevel() = 1
FOR XML PATH'file'), ROOT('files'), TYPE
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the `file` node to each column:

```
SELECT [stream_id] AS 'file/@stream_id'
   , [is_system] AS 'file/@is_system'
   , [is_temporary] AS 'file/@is_temporary'
   ...
   , [name] AS 'file'
FROM Merged
FOR XML PATH('files'), TYPE;
```